# How do I export a copy of a .doc file, renamed in R, into a new folder using RStudio?

Tags: r, copy, rename, move

I have a folder of word documents, R has rename them (thank you @gregor Thomas for helping fix that issue). The original folder has the original name.

species name 2 of 10 [C] 27.Aug.12 [Fr#2046] location name.doc

R has renamed with the field record number at the start

2046 species name 2 of 10 [C] 27.Aug.12 [Fr#2046] location name.doc

I have an output_folder where I want the renamed copies sent, but I can't copy and paste with the new name into this folder. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(stringr)            #install stingr from library
my_path <- "/Users/Documents/RStudio_Docs/Field_Record_Rename/original_folder"  # Define working directory
my_path                 # Print path to working directory
file_names_old <- list.files(my_path)              # Get current file names
file_names_old                            # Print current file names
x = file_names_old
x
my_new_path <- "/Users/Documents/RStudio_Docs/Field_Record_Rename/output_folder"
my_new_path
fr = str_extract(x, "(?<=Fr#)\\d+")
file_names_new = paste (fr, x)
file_names_new
file.rename(paste0(my_path, file_names_old),
            paste0(my_new_path, file_names_new))
```

I have over 3,000 records to rename, thank you for any help.

Comment: Sound like you are not trying to rename files but rather copy them to a new location with a new name. If this is the case you should try using file.copy instead of file.rename

Comment: True, so I need to copy and rename it at the same time. Any advice on how to do this would be great. Thank you

Comment: you could use file.copy and just give it a new name in the arguments

Comment: I've tried to add the file.copy but without luck. `path <-"/Users/Documents/RStudio_Docs/Field_Record_Rename/output_folder" newfolder <-"NEW" 
dir.create(file.path(dirname(path),newfolder)) 
file.copy(file_names_new,"newfolder")`

Comment: using the code from your question try running`file.copy(paste0(my_path, file_names_old), paste0(my_new_path, file_names_new))`. It would really help if you could give a couple of examples of what you expect to happen

Comment: Thank you @GordonShumway you have been super helpful. I am looking for is taking over 3,000 word documents, file name format 'species name 2 of 10 [C] 27.Aug.12 [Fr#2046] location name.doc'. Currently in subfolders, but I will copy them into a master folder. From the master folder I want to rename them all, format  with the number at the front '2046 species name 2 of 10 [C] 27.Aug.12 [Fr#2046] location name.doc'. I want new copies of the word documents moved into a new folder, 'output_folder'.  I had tried the file.copy previously, but can't get it to work. I am getting FALSE messages.

Comment: Can you give an example of two paths one for the old file and one for the new?

Comment: example of paths:

Old files: `Users/name/Documents/RStudio_Docs/Field_Record_Rename/old_names`

New files:
`Users/name/Documents/RStudio_Docs/Field_Record_Rename/output_folder`

Comment: can share a full path with the file name

Comment: @GordonShumway this is an example of the orignal file path and name: `Users/name/Documents/RStudio_Docs/Field_Record_Rename/old_names/species name 2 of 10 [C] 27.Aug.12 [Fr#2046] location name.doc` With the output name to come from the file.rename action and be copied into the folder: `Users/name/Documents/RStudio_Docs/Field_Record_Rename/output_folder` I've change the names of some folders and details from the .doc file name, but its otherwise the same. Thank you

Comment: I still need help in applying a document copy, paste and rename onto my word docs, and pasting copies into a new folder after applying the new name from the file_name_new output. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work to copy files to a new location:

```
file.copy(from = file.path(my_path, file_names_old),
          to = file.path(my_new_path, file_names_new))
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon, that is a massive help. The file copy and rename has worked. I'll have a go at batch renaming all the docs now.